# Define a sequentiel approval steps

Tags: approval-process

I'm working with approval process, and I want to define a sequtial approval steps, and where I choose the approval manually!

For example: I choose 3 approvers

When approver1 approve => Approbation email send to approver2

approvere2 approve => approbation email send to approver3

approver3 approve => record approved

any idea?!

Comment: What did you already try ?

Answer (score 1):

This is standard functionality, please see the help documentation here: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=approvals_creating_approval_processes.htm&language=en_US